# How to add an image to xml sheet using css

Tags: css, xml, image

How would I add a small triangle image located locally on my machine at that location to the beginning of the table line?

Heres my CSS

```
stock:nth-child(1){
    display:table-row;
    content: url('..\stock\down.gif');
    color:red;
}
```

And the corresponding XML

```
  <stock class="down">
     <symbol>AAPL</symbol>
     <company>Apple Computer, Inc.</company>
     <lastSale>$15.26</lastSale>
     <netChange>-0.17</netChange>
     <pChange>-1.10%</pChange>
     <volume>5.548</volume>
  </stock>
```

Here is a much much better way to write the css

```
stock[class~=down]{
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    display:block;
    background: url("down.gif") no-repeat;
    color:red;
```

}

Comment: you may wish to look into xslt which is a styling language specific to xml. It allows css

Comment: So are you saying that there is no way? Im going to be learning xslt in the near future but this project was supposed to be completed with just css.

Comment: It is possible, but it's easier with XSLT.  See example how to style with straight XML and css below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a lot easier to do this with XSLT, where you can run a foreach across each of the children in your file and apply styles from a spreadsheet, but you can do this with XML and CSS.  You'll need to set the headers in your xml file, and then call the stylesheet, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"?>

  <stock class="down">
     <symbol>AAPL</symbol>
     <company>Apple Computer, Inc.</company>
     <lastSale>$15.26</lastSale>
     <netChange>-0.17</netChange>
     <pChange>-1.10%</pChange>
     <volume>5.548</volume>
  </stock>
```

Then you just need to modify your CSS file to make whatever changes you like.

For instance:

(Edit for image):

```
stock  {
    display:block;
    margin-left:20px;
}

symbol {
    display: list-item;
    list-style: url("..\stock\down.gif");

}
company {
    display: list-item;
    list-style: url("..\stock\down.gif");
}
```

You can then change this how you like, in the same way you'd style for HTML

Comment: Yeah I do have the css referenced in my xml. Those are just clips of the issue I'm having. I have the xml styled using css tables.  I was wondering how I add an image using css. The code that I used "content: url('..\stock\down.gif');"  did not work to add the image.

Comment: @DallanBaker okay I edited it to include an image (I tested something similar, so it should work)

Comment: Alright I did try using that and it did not work. Is there a way to do that within my stock:nth-child(1) element? Is that line how I would correctly point to an image on my local machine?

Comment: it should work.   try moving the file to the the same directory and just try this: `list-style: url("down.gif");`  I noticed it does not work if it can't find the file.  You can definitely change the bullet style here

Comment: Okay I tried that line `stock:nth-child(1){
 display:list-item;
 list-style: url("down.gif");
 color:red;
}`  and it still was unable to display the image (yeah sorry about that didn't know how to add code to comments thank you)

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying

Comment: but a backtick before and after any code you want to paste in the comments

Comment: I'm not sure why.  try it with the specific element before you try nth-child  (also, I recommend using `stock :nth-child(n)`  specifically.  copy and paste (note there's a space)

Comment: Okay I put in in just the `stock{}` element and it still was unable to display the image.  Is the fact that im using tables for the rest of the css messing things up?

Comment: that could be it.  I was just starting from scratch.  try a fresh style sheet, or try it for one of the child nodes

Comment: okay I tried a fresh stylesheet with just `stock{
 display:list-item;
 list-style: url("down.gif");
}` and it is still not working. The image is certainly in the same directory. It displays all the stock elements as a list but does not add the image for some reason

Comment: just copy and paste what I have above in the answer.  That should definitely work;  I tried it with your exact code (with a different image of course, and in a local directory)

Comment: not with `stock`.  for stock you need to display:block; and use the margin as above

Comment: okay I was able to get it to display in the fresh stylesheet using this code `stock{
 float:left;
 display:list-item;
 list-style: url("down.gif");
}` which also really messes up the list display. Also am I going to need to rewrite my css to use lists instead of tables? The project had indicated that I should use tables.

Comment: I said nothing about float left.  Please read the instructions I provided.

Comment: okay I did copy and past the code it did work needed more margin space though thank you. Also was able to get it to incorporate into my existing code now.

Comment: great!  I knew we would get it eventually :)